# How to fix 'map[] does not contain declared merge key: name' error when I edit and save the pod yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-secrets

I 'm trying to pull an image from a private registry. But the status of pod is 'ImagePullBackOff', which means I need to add a secret to the pod.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                  From                                          Message
  ----     ------   ----                 ----                                          -------
  Normal   Pulling  52m (x255 over 22h)  kubelet, cn-huhehaote.i-hp3fkfzlcf1u9cigq2h7  pulling image "xxx/fcp"
  Normal   BackOff  8m (x5597 over 22h)  kubelet, cn-huhehaote.i-hp3fkfzlcf1u9cigq2h7  Back-off pulling image "xxx/fcp"
  Warning  Failed   3m (x5618 over 22h)  kubelet, cn-huhehaote.i-hp3fkfzlcf1u9cigq2h7  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

So I added the following code in pod yaml.

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: private-reg-container
        image: <your-private-image>
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-secret
```

Then I got

```
error: map: map[] does not contain declared merge key: name
```

The solution I searched out is to delete 'imagePullSecret', which doesn't work for me. I wonder how to fix the error. Can anyone help me?

kubectl version is

```
 kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.5", GitCommit:"753b2dbc622f5cc417845f0ff8a77f539a4213ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:41:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.5", GitCommit:"753b2dbc622f5cc417845f0ff8a77f539a4213ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:31:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Can you share which version of Kubernetes you are using? Paste the output for `kubectl version`. Also, instead of a snippet, can you share your full Pod yaml code?

Comment: I just paste the output please check. The pod is controller-manager pod. I haven't edited the yaml code before. I failed to initialize federation control plane. Kubefed init says "waiting for the federation control plane to come up" but it never comes up, so I checked the pod status and found this error.

Comment: So you are trying to use your custom version for the controller-manager?

Comment: @fiunchinho Yes, I follow the direction [Building Kubernetes cluster federation](https://github.com/kubernetes/federation), but can't pull the image.

Comment: Not helpful, but it looks like cluster federation is deprecated https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/federation/set-up-cluster-federation-kubefed/

Comment: Thank you all the same. I've followed this guide before and found kubefed init failed because the image given is not available.

Comment: Added community wiki answer for future

Answer (score 8):

I've stumbled with the same problem (using helm) and I've found out, that it is not allowed to edit the `imagePullSecret` section in the deployment...

The solution was to delete the deployment and recreate it.

Comment: As far as I know, It is possible to use patch syntax for this. For example: kubectl -n example patch deployment mydeployment -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "registry"}]}', if deployment deletion is not the case.

Comment: @DariyN and --force flag (I'm not sure if it's kubectl or oc extension), but generally, helm fail in that case...

Answer (score 0):

Things may be different now in early 2023.  I didn't have to delete the deployment (fortunately).

I had to delete the existing (empty) imagePullSecrets and then patch them.  So:

```
# Delete existing imagePullSecret
kubectl patch deployment my-deploy \
  --type=json \
  -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/spec/imagePullSecrets"}]'

# Now add the correct one
kubectl patch deployment my-deploy \
  --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "my-registry-creds"}]}}}}'
```

Answer (score -2):

As @fiunchinho mentioned in comments and as per [Federation with Kubefed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/federation/set-up-cluster-federation-kubefed/) - cluster federation is deprecated.

> Use of Federation v1 is strongly discouraged. Federation V1 never
>   achieved GA status and is no longer under active development.
>   Documentation is for historical purposes only.

The solution is to use  [Kubernetes Federation v2](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/federation-v2).
For more details you can refer to [Federation v2 user guide](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/federation-v2/blob/master/docs/userguide.md) and [Federation v development guide](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/federation-v2/blob/master/docs/development.md)

Comment: I fail to see the connection between that answer and the question....

Comment: "I just paste the output please check. The pod is controller-manager pod. I haven't edited the yaml code before. I failed to initialize federation control plane. Kubefed init says "waiting for the federation control plane to come up" but it never comes up, so I checked the pod status and found this error. – Xiang Li Apr 17 at 9:56 "